# Is it ok to use spec/valid? for function input validation at runtime?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am writing a clojure library, and I am thinking on using clojure.spec. Is it good practice to use spec/valid? on functions input at runtime? or should I use destracturing along with type hints? I am concerned, if there will be a performance penalty, and if it's considered bad use of spec, and generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always appropriate to check for valid inputs "where appropriate".  What does that mean?  That is an open question.

In general, the most "dangerous" inputs will be coming from the outside world, at the boundaries of your program.  This means input from the web/browser, or perhaps from another service.

The "safest" inputs are deep inside your program, where (presumably) you have more control and confidence.  For example, you would (probably) never check the inputs to the `+` function to ensure each arg was a number.  And, even if an invalid arg slipped by (a string, perhaps), the JVM would throw an exception right away.

For sure, you should have maximal checking when running unit tests, so at least you know your code is working properly in the "normal" path.  I like to use [Plumatic Schema](https://github.com/plumatic/schema) for this as it is easy to have validation always run during unit tests, but is off by default during "production" runs.

Having said that, I often place assert statements at the beginning of functions where a bad input would be difficult to recognize or would really cause hard-to-diagnose problems later on.

Both of these techniques have saved me many times!

Note that even a strongly typed language like Java won't save you here.  Typed variables may ensure that an input is a number, but it could be invalid like sending a negative value to the `sqrt` function.  Other functions may have even more restrictive inputs, such as only being valid for prime numbers, etc.  Types cannot capture these detailed requirements.  Only good design and good testing can prevent these problems.

Types & asserts cannot prevent all problems, but they are like guard rails on the road (or seatbelts & airbags).  They may not be able to prevent a crash, but they can provide early warning and reduce the severity of the consequences.

---

P.S.  You can see how I like to balance the trade-off between safety & cost of checking in [a libary I wrote](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  Be sure to [see the file `_bootstrap.clj`](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/cljc/_bootstrap.cljc) which is a trick to turn on the Plumatic Schema tests only during unit tests.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, as I understand it, I should use it in runtime, only for critical/complicated functions? and would it be wrong for checking input structure of a dsl like library?To check for example if an input is a vector of 2 elements, which the first one would be an int and the second one a double.

Comment: When in doubt, verify.  Why not always verify the type of input args until you are certain you don't need to or can no longer afford to?

Comment: ok that helped, with the confusion I had, I started specing every function like a mad man ☺️